# jboss 6.2 EAP unable to add mysql datasource and module

Tags: mysql, jboss, datasource

I am having trouble to add a mysql jdbc driver to my jboss 6.2 EAP.  I followed each step as described there : [Install a JDBC Driver as a Core Module](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html)

but whenever I try to create datasource in command line, jboss return this message:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add(driver-name=mysql,driver-module-name=com.mysql,driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource)
        {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "failure-description" => "JBAS014749: Operation handler failed: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql is already registered",
        "rolled-back" => true
    }
```

I obtain the same message at boot time when I try to manually add datasource configuration to my standalone-full.xml file.

I placed my jar driver in EAP_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main/ and this is my module configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql"> 
    <resources>  
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar" />  
    </resources>
    <dependencies>  
        <module name="javax.api"/>  
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
    </dependencies>  
</module>
```

My development environment: ubuntu 14.04, sun jdk 7 or 8.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by 2 entries in `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` in the MySQL JDBC driver JAR:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```

JBoss EAP 6.2 probably doesn't expect more than 1 entry there. I filled [an issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1107120) with the problem description.

Nevertheless, you can define value for **`driver-class-name`** attribute in the CLI command and you should get the expected behavior:

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mysql:add( \
  driver-name=mysql, \
  driver-module-name=com.mysql, \
  driver-xa-datasource-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource, \
  driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)
```

Answer (score 6):

@kwart's answer didn't work for me (running on JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14), using mysql-connector-java-5.1.32 jdbc driver), I fixed it by adding the following directly to standalone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <!-- snip -->
            <drivers>

                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>

            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Make sure the server is stopped when you do this otherwise the change will disappear..

Comment: nice... exactly this worked for me in JBoss AS 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with an old version driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar

org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql is already registered -> https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/878573

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar and solved it by using an old version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar. 
The server now starts properly